# Magento CE and SUPEE-8967 filename implies EE?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8967

I need to patch a Magento **CE** installation with [SUPEE-8967]

> https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?_ga=2.17348479.775257066.1494499183-1580976029.1489398169#download2005

The downloaded file is named **PATCH_SUPEE-8967_EE_1.13.1.0_v1-2017-05-02-04-21-21.sh**.

That **EE** worries me: how can I be sure that this will work on **CE** too and it's not a SNAFU from the release team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We applied the patch to the Magento CE installation on a dev enviroment with no issue, so it looks to be just a naming imperfection in the patch filename.

Answer (score -1):

All Magento patches contain the SUPEE string. There's actually no way of getting Enterprise patches through the public site. You need to be a registered Enterprise user and logged in to even get access to the Enterprise patches.

Comment: Clearly, I was not referring to "" in "SUPEE" but to the **_EE_** part of the filename.